# How to make testing process automatic flex release?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, flexbuilder

I posted the same question but I think it was not so clear. Now I am rephrasing my question with real problem.

I have a flex application. It is basically a web application. On it I have a player that play avi files and some buttons and tabs along side.

The application also have recording button that records that direct stream from an IP cam and store that stream on the media (USB).

How can I automate function testing of such application. Like I have confusion that when I press the recording button but can I be sure that recording starts? I have tried RIATest and flexUnit 4.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: FlexUnit is for unit/integration tests, not functional tests.
Have you embedded automation libs in your application?

Comment: how can I add automation libs in my application? where Can I find them and how can I use them?

Comment: automation libs are provided with the Flex SDK if you have flash builder premium.
See the Flex or RIATest documentation to add them in your project

Comment: I am using flex sdks 3.5.0. but these files are not there in the "sdks/framework/automation.swc" "sdks/framework/automation_agent.swc".

Comment: yes , as said before, you only get them if you have the professional version of flex builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want FlexMonkey:  http://flexmonkey.gorillalogic.com/

Comment: Yeah I am now using Flex monkey. I had sdk 3.5 before. when I checked the libs folder the automation stuff was not there. so I switched to sdk 3.2 and now flex monkey is working. I am in the process of check...If I will get any problem I will share...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should include automation libs in your project as well as the RIATest agent (if you use RIATest of course)

http://www.riatest.com/onlinedocs/v3/RIATest/CompilingWithAgent.html

Comment: Yeah I am now using Flex monkey. I had sdk 3.5 before. when I checked the libs folder the automation stuff was not there. so I switched to sdk 3.2 and now flex monkey is working. I am in the process of check...If I will get any problem I will share...Thanks